# Computer slows down

Tags: 15.10, memory-usage, memory-leak

I am running latest Ubuntu having upgraded (twice now I think). When I boot up, my computer is using 600Mb of memory. I then use 3 instances of Chrome with multiple tabs, Atom and VS Code and run gulp in the terminal.

After a day, my computer is often much slower. If I close everything I am still using 3Gb of an 8Gb machine, and I may have used a very little of the swap partition. There is a little background network connection going on. It ends up being easiest just to reboot, but that is not what I expect from Linux.

Should I be worried, should I change something?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to debug the situation more with `vmstat` (package `procps`), `iostat` (package `sysstat`), iotop (package `iotop`). Looking for those tools in google yields many guides about finding system's bottleneck.